# Hash Tables Stay Sorted?

Tags: data-structures, hash, hashtable

My question is not asking if you can sort a pre-existing hash table, but if I may the keys to the right indices will they stay sorted?

For example, if I need to have a hash table of persons where I hash their birth year and I want the youngest always below the eldest. if I do quadratic probing to rehash it'll still have the youngest under the eldest. It sounds logical but what cases would the order break?

tl;dr If I have the hash table hash the keys to an order index will they stay sorted even during rehashing?

Comment: Your question is difficult to read... also, it seems what you are asking is dependent on the concrete hash table implementation. Are you asking about a particular language? If so, please add the relevant tag.

Comment: Im writing in C++ but its just a data structure question. I'm not asking how to make one or anything just about the nature of the hash table.

Comment: Basically if my hash function does it by oldest to youngest, then its basically sorted  right? And will it stay sorted by quadratic probing implementations?

Comment: In general a hash table just maps keys to values, the order in which it stores key/value pairs is implementation specific. For example, the Java HashMap says "This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant over time."

Comment: They don't 'stay' sorted, because they are never sorted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I am concluding your question is related to C++. The hash table implementations in C++ are part of STL . And they are std::unordered_map/unordered_multimap and std::unordered_set/unordered_multiset.

If you prefer to get sorted output from a data structure, call should goes to std:map/multimap or std::set/multiset. Please note here the implementation is not hashtable instead they are using binary tree as basic data structure.

Comment: Haha so I'm not using the STL im using Weiss's implementation of the Quadratic Probing Hash Table and he uses a vector implementation (pretty much a fancy array in my head) This is for my own self knowledge but this helped knowing its implementation dependent.